# Webhook vs HTTP POST/PUT?

Tags: http-post, webhooks, http-put

Webhook is said to be push style communication which enables an application to push data to another application.

With HTTP POST/PUT also we can send data to another application.

So how are two different at conceptual level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same thing. A *webhook* is a callback or event listener concept for the web that is implemented as an HTTP PUT or POST. It could be implemented as a GET if this information is small.

To make it work, you register your *webhook* address with someone else's server. It could be an address like https://yourcompany.com/notifyme. Then that other server will send an HTTP PUT or POST request to the address you registered when some event occurs.

I think this is confusing because the terms *web* and *hook* are so broad that they are almost meaningless. A *hook* is something a pirate replaces his missing hand with. The terms *API callback* or *listener API* would be much more intuitive.